# How to call an Oracle Packaged Function from Excal

Tags: excel, oracle, vba, stored-procedures

I am trying execute a Package and Function in an Oracle 11g database.
I have the following code, however, I get an error on the first **.Execute** command.

The Locals window in VBA gives me the following on the error:

```
Description : "Unspecified error" : String
Number : -2147467259 : Long
Source : "OraOLEDB" : String
```

Oh, I have referenced the Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 6.1 Library.

I've tried various changes to the code however they all return the same error message.

```
Sub QueryGLComb()

Dim OraCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim objErr As ADODB.Error
Dim lngRow As Long

On Error GoTo err_test

Set OraCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
OraCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" & _
                          "Data Source=DEMO;" & _
                          "User ID=scott;" & _
                          "Password=tiger;"
OraCon.Open
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = OraCon

If OraCon.State = adStateClosed Then
    MsgBox "false"
End If

With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = OraCon
  .CommandText = "fnd_flex_keyval.validate_segs"
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  .CommandTimeout = 60
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("return", adBoolean, adParamReturnValue)
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("operation", adVariant, adParamInput, , "CHECK_COMBINATION")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("appl_short_name", adVariant, adParamInput, , "SQLGL")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("key_flex_code", adVariant, adParamInput, , "GL#")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("structure_number", adNumeric, adParamInput, , "50268")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("concat_segments", adVariant, adParamInput, , "67000.2400.4001.01")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("validation_date", adVariant, adParamInput, , "sysdate")
  .Execute
End With

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = OraCon
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = OraCon
  .CommandText = "begin FND_FLEX_KEYVAL.ERROR_MESSAGE"
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("message", adVariant, adParamReturnValue)
  .Execute
End With

MsgBox "Return Message = " & cmd.Parameters(0)

OraCon.Close

err_test:
    MsgBox Error$
    For Each objErr In OraCon.Errors
        MsgBox objErr.Description
    Next
    OraCon.Errors.Clear
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

The first ".Execute" line is where the error occurs.

Here is the Oracle code I use in SQLDeveloper/Toad. The package I am calling is "FND_FLEX_VALIDATE", and the function is "VALIDATE_SEGS". This is an Oracle provided package in Oracle eBS. If the initial call to fnd_flex_keyval.validate_segs returns true, then all is good. If it returns an error, then we have to call "FND_FLEX_KEYVAL.ERROR_MESSAGE" to retrieve the error message.

```
DECLARE
    l_return  boolean;
    l_message varchar2(240); 
BEGIN
    l_return := fnd_flex_keyval.validate_segs(operation => 'CHECK_COMBINATION'
                                           ,appl_short_name => 'SQLGL'
                                           ,key_flex_code => 'GL#'
                                           ,structure_number => 50268 --- Pass your chart of accounts id
                                           ,concat_segments => '67000.2400.4001.01' --- Pass your account combination string you want to create
                                           ,validation_date => sysdate); --- effective date by which you want the combination to be validated

   l_message := FND_FLEX_KEYVAL.ERROR_MESSAGE;
    If l_return THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Valid');
    Else
        dbms_output.put_line(l_message);
    End if;
END;
```

I've create a new file to test on. The procedure I'm trying to execute now has 3 parameters: 1 in, 2 out. Again, I still receive the same error when the code gets to the **.Execute** command.

```
Sub ExecutePackageP()

Dim OraCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim objErr As ADODB.Error
Dim lngRow As Long

On Error GoTo err_test

Set OraCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

OraCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" & _
                          "Data Source=demo;" & _
                          "User ID=scott;" & _
                          "Password=tiger;"
OraCon.Open
cmd.ActiveConnection = OraCon

If OraCon.State = adStateClosed Then
    MsgBox "false"
End If

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = OraCon
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "XXX_VALIDATE_ACCOUNT"
    .CommandTimeout = 60
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("param1", adVariant, adParamInput, , "67000.2400.4001.01")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("param2", adBoolean, adParamOutput)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("param3", adVariant, adParamOutput)
    .Execute
End With

MsgBox "Reurtn = P_CCID=" & cmd.Parameters(1) & "; P_RESULT=" & cmd.Parameters(2) & ";"

OraCon.Close
End sub
```

I changed the parameter type from adVariant to adVarchar and received an error message stating that the Parameter object is improperly defined. Only adVariant seems to work. I kind of recall a site that showed the types to use when executing against different databases, and it said for varchar2 to use adVariant.
Adding in procedure code for xxx_validate_account: (Note, this procedure calls an internal oracle function called fnd_flex_ext.get_ccid)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPS."XXX_VALIDATE_ACCOUNT" (p_account_flex in varchar2,
                         p_valid out boolean,
                         p_message out varchar2) is

x_structure_id number;
x_ccid number := 0;

pragma autonomous_transaction;

begin

execute immediate 'alter session set nls_language = ''AMERICAN''';

p_valid := false;

select chart_of_accounts_id
into x_structure_id
from gl_ledgers
where short_name = 'XXX';

x_ccid := fnd_flex_ext.get_ccid(application_short_name => 'SQLGL',
                        key_flex_code => 'GL#',
                        structure_number => x_structure_id,
                        validation_date => to_char(sysdate,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),
                        concatenated_segments => p_account_flex);

if x_ccid > 0 then
    p_valid := true;
    commit;
else
    p_valid := false;
    p_message := fnd_message.get;
end if;

exception when others then
        p_message := sqlerrm;
        p_valid := false;

end xxx_validate_account;
/
```

Update: 25/09/2015:
Unfortunately I can't update the package, due to other packages and apps using it.
So, I decided to create a new package with a simple function to play with.
I made sure that the input and output aren't boolean to take that issue out of play. 
For the life of me though, I still get the same issue!
I tried to use "adVarchar,100" in the parameter string, but excel just keeps telling me that the arguments are of the wrong type. Seriously thinking there is some kind of issue with my machine...

New function and code to follow:

```
create or replace package apps.xxxx_return_username is 
function return_username (p_user_id in number) return varchar2;
end xxxx_return_username;
/
create or replace package body apps.xxxx_return_username as
function return_username(p_user_id in number) return varchar2 is
x_user_name varchar2(100);
begin
select user_name into x_user_name
from apps.fnd_user where user_id = p_user_id;
return x_user_name;
exception
  when no_data_found then return 'xxxxx';
end return_username;
end xxxx_return_username;
/


Sub newfunctioncall()

Dim OraCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

Set OraCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

OraCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" & _
                          "Data Source=demo;" & _
                          "User ID=scott;" & _
                          "Password=tiger;"
OraCon.Open
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = OraCon

If OraCon.State = adStateClosed Then
    MsgBox "false"
End If

Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("param1", adNumeric, adParamInput, , "15483")
cmd.Parameters.Append param1
Set param2 = cmd.CreateParameter("param2", adVariant, , adParamReturnValue)
cmd.Parameters.Append param2

cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "xxecu_return_username.return_username"
Set recset = cmd.Execute

MsgBox "Reurtn = USERNAME=" & cmd.Parameters(0)

OraCon.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: If you comment out the `On Error` which line raises the error?

Comment: Hi Tim. The first ".Execute" line is where the error occurs.

Comment: Can you add the code for `XXX_VALIDATE_ACCOUNT`?  Also, one of the changes I suggested in my answer was to switch from `adVariant` to the actual datatype, in most cases it was a `adVarchar`.

Comment: Just had a thought. I'm using Excel 32-bit, but have Oracle Client 64bit installed. Could that be an issue? Not sure if i can install both 32 and 64 clients, and then somehow choose which one to use in excel.

Comment: However, i just thought. In the same workbook, i have a macro to perform a simple sql query of the same database and that works 100%. so now thinking it may not be a driver issue.

Comment: The 32/64 bit issue would likely only apply if you were using ODBC.  Since you are using a native client, I wouldn't think that a culprit.  At any rate, the failure would occur on the connect, not the execute.  I'll look at your edits now and see if anything jumps out.

Comment: @RussH, I could be wrong, but I think the Boolean issue I mentioned as an annoyance may be the core issue -- please see my revised response.

Answer (score 1):

Good job on describing the background of your problem...

I see a couple of possible places where things could go wrong.  Without knowing exactly which it might be, I think this is an example of a working piece of code that would do what you seek -- although I admit I may have a couple of things wrong.

First off, in your procedure, if you declare your variables as parameters:

```
create or replace procedure validate_segs(
  operation in varchar2,
  appl_short_name in varchar2,
  key_flex_code in varchar2,
  structure_number in number,
  concat_segments in varchar2,
  validation_date in date,
  message out varchar2,
  results out numeric
) as
BEGIN
  message := 'Hello';
  results := 1;
END;
```

Then, within VBA I think you can do something like this.  With VBA/OleDB and Oracle, I've never gotten Booleans to behave.  They work fine in C#, but I haven't had success with VBA, so I converted it to a number for this example, which always seems to cast to a boolean within VBA.

```
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = OraCon
  .CommandText = "validate_segs"
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  .CommandTimeout = 60
  .NamedParameters = True

  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
      "operation", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "CHECK_COMBINATION")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
      "appl_short_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "SQLGL")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
      "key_flex_code", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "GL#")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
      "structure_number", adNumeric, adParamInput, 10, 50268)
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
      "concat_segments", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "67000.2400.4001.01")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
      "validation_date", adDate, adParamInput, , Now())
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("message", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 255)
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("return", adNumeric, adParamOutput, 1)
  .Execute
End With
```

Then, to actually mine the results from the stored procedure:

```
Dim result As Boolean
Dim message As String

message = cmd.Parameters(6).Value
result = cmd.Parameters(7).Value
```

I realize you may be locked into VBA, but on the off chance you have the choice, .NET's interface provides a much better environment for debugging this sort of thing.

-- EDIT 9/24/15 --

I think your code is nearly there, but there are two remaining issues I can see, one of which I'm not 100% sure is an issue but I think the other is.  I eluded to this earlier in my solution, but I now think this might be the core issue:  it seems OLEDB and Oracle Booleans don't play nicely together.  See this article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306530

To resolve this, if you switch it to a number in Oracle and in your VBA, it should work.

The other issue, which I'm not sure is real or not, is you are using the Variant Db type when I think you should be using the string (or Varchar) Db Type.  You mentioned you saw in the docs to use variant, so maybe this doesn't matter...  but the Varchar will work.  You do need the additional parameter of the length of the text for it to compile properly (I used 255 for kicks).

So, the two changes I would suggest are:

1)  Change from Boolean to number in your stored proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "XXX_VALIDATE_ACCOUNT" (
   p_account_flex in varchar2, p_valid out number, p_message out varchar2) is
      -- blah blah blah
   p_valid := 0;
```

2) Change your VBA code to expect a number back (and convert Variant to Varchar)

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("param1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, _
    "67000.2400.4001.01")
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("param2", adNumeric, adParamOutput)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("param3", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 255)
```

even if you cast it as a boolean

```
Dim result As Boolean
result = cmd.Parameters(1).Value
```

And I must say, the error message that the debugger returned on this was not helpful at all.

Comment: Hi Hambone. Thank you for your reply. I've setup a new file to try connecting to Oracle to test against a different procedure.
This procedure has one 1 input as varchar2, 2 out's, 1 being boolean and 1 being varchar2. I have put the new code in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know you are executing a valid command in the Oracle database? You might want to try it out first using SQLplus. Don't quite know where you function call is. It might be:

```
begin FND_FLEX_KEYVAL.ERROR_MESSAGE
```

But that will is not a complete statement. At least it needs the following.

```
begin 
   FND_FLEX_KEYVAL.ERROR_MESSAGE; 
end;
```

However, if FND_FLEX_KEYVAL.ERROR_MESSAGE is a function the previous code won't run either. In that case you want to select the function value:

```
select FND_FLEX_KEYVAL.ERROR_MESSAGE from dual
```